# how to send JSON to HTML file using flask?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm at a beginner at coding and i'm stuck at the final closing :|
i'm using python 2.7
this is my **serever.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,jsonify
import requests
import json
import new

app = Flask(__name__)

#serve homepage
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def homepage():
   return render_template('page2.html')
 
@app.route('/page3.html', methods=["POST"])
def result_matchup():
    h= request.form['h']
    a= request.form['a']
    l= request.form['l']
    p= request.form['p']
    result = json.dumps(new.calc(h,a,l,p))
    
    return render_template('page3.html',result=result)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when i ask for `return result` for checking myself, this is the output:

```
{"f": 197.1, "k": 196}
```

this is my page3.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <center><h1>Final = {{f}}</h1></center>

</body>
</html>
```

the output for all this is
**"Final = "**
,while I expect for **Final = 197.1.**

what am I doing wrong? any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `new.calc` returns a dictionary.  No need to use `json.dumps` to stringify that before passing to your template.  So instead try:

```
result = new.calc(h,a,l,p)
```

`result` should now be a dictionary, with the keys `'f'` and `'k'`

Therefor in the template you should access this dictionary, as you would in python:

```
<center><h1>Final = {{result['f']}}</h1></center>
```

I would also advise using a later version of python since `2.7` is unsupported now, and making this change early will prevent you having to make already written code, `3.x` compatible later.

Comment: {{result['f']}}

amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

You serialize your result as JSON writing `result = json.dumps(new.calc(h,a,l,p))`. However, you should directly pass a Python object to `render_template`. In fact, that's one of the strengths of Jinja templating: You do not need to pass JSON, but you can handle Python objects directly. So just write `result = new.calc(h,a,l,p)`.

Second, within the Jinja template, you have to access the objects as you passed them through your `render_template` function. In your case, `<center><h1>Final = {{result['f]}}</h1></center>` should do the job.